# VBA/Excel: How to highlight a cell based on changes for only 1 column

Tags: vba

I have a small macro that highlights cells when they are edited based on what month it is.  I would like to make this subroutine happen for only Column D.  Is there a way to do this?  Code is below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Month(Date)
Case Is = 1
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
Case Is = 2
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
Case Is = 3
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
Case Is = 4
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 18
Case Is = 5
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
Case Is = 6
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Case Is = 7
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Case Is = 8
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
Case Is = 9
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
Case Is = 10
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 31
Case Is = 11
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
Case Is = 12
Range(curCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
curCell = ActiveCell.Address(Columns(0, 0))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("D"))
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        ' proceed with r here instead of Target
        ' ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Actually, it seems you didn't use Target right yet. It gives you the Range Object where the change has taken place. You don't need that curCell.

Comment: Do you mean that all of the curCell's are unnecessary or that the 2nd sub containing the curCell statement is unnecessary?

Comment: All of them (most likely). In `Worksheet_Change`, `target` already gives you all cells that have been changed. This _can_ be multiple cells. So why bother saving the current cell's address in the background? Just try `r.Interior.Colorindex = ...` in all those lines in your code (combined with the code that I posted).